# The dlib library does not import in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror

I added the `dlib` library and it is shown in the environments in anaconda, but every time I run the code
an error is showing up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-04aff462cee7> in <module>
      1 import cv2
----> 2 import dlib
      3 
      4 from scipy.spatial import distance
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlib'
```

Answer (score 0):

first remove installed dlib and deactivate from env and return to your env again.
you have to first install Cython:

```
pip install cython
```

and then install dlib:

```
pip install dlib
```